# Removing spaces from For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, space

When creating a for loop, it appears that python adds spaces.

```
menuItems = ['apple', 'banana', 'car', 'thing', 'whatever', 'burrito']

menuNum = 1
for menuItem in menuItems:
    print menuNum,'. ',menuItem
    menuNum = menuNum + 1
```

returns this

```
1 .  apple
2 .  banana
3 .  car
```

etc...

Any idea on how I can simply get this without the spacing?

eg.

```
1. apple
2. banana
3. car
```

Comment: Your last list still contains spaces, is that how its supposed to be?

Comment: What does this have to do with a `for` loop aside from your `print` statement being inside one? In other words, why do you think this problem is being caused by `for`?

Answer (score 4):

Use string formatting. `print` in Python 2 puts a space for each comma used to separate the items.

```
>>> data = ['apple', 'banana', 'car', 'thing', 'whatever', 'burrito']
for i, item in enumerate(data, 1):
    print '{}. {}'.format(i, item)
...     
1. apple
2. banana
3. car
4. thing
5. whatever
6. burrito
```

And use `enumerate` if you want index as well items.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of Python's formatting capabilities.

```
print "{} . {}".format(menuNum, menuItem)  # 2.7+ or 3.x

print "%d . %s" % (menuNum, menuItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` expression in Python 2 puts spaces between the items on a single line. To avoid this, create a single string first that looks like you want to output to appear:

```
# string formatting
for menuItem in menuItems:
    print '{0}. {1}'.format(menuNum, menuItem)
```

Or else, use the Python3 `print` function, which has more options available.

```
# print function
from __future__ import print_function

for menuItem in menuItems:
    print(menuNum, '. ', menuItem, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(menuNum, '. ', menuItem, sep='')
```

You could also use string formatting:

```
print '{0}. {1}'.format(menuNum, menuItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after the ". " when using a comma and printing, a space is inserted for you. 
Altough I use python 3.3, as far as I'm aware, using '+' should still work. Unless I'm missing something; the following would work fine.

```
print menuNum + '.' + menuItem
```